# Converting Linux codes to Batch file format to be run in MS-DOS

Tags: linux, batch-file, dos

What is this block of code from linux intended to do and how do i code the equivalent that is supposed to do similar thing in MS-DOS?

```
#DB=CARMPAS1
[ $# -gt 0 ] && DB=$1 || DB=CARMPAS1

#  if [ !$3 ]; then
#     echo -e "\nplease enter database name, username and user password.   Usage : rebuild_db.sh <db_name>  <user_name> <password>\n"
#     exit 1
#   else if [ $1 == "load" ]; then
#      load
#      exit 0 
#  fi
```

I dont know why those parts were commented out but i guess they were intended to do something that was not successful. Perhaps a declaration and a condition to for some script to be run

Comment: Where did you learn that MS-DOS runs on Windows NT?

Comment: just wanted to avoid any further questions like which windows OS and the likes...my bad...i didn't get to learn it though but i guess i am now. trying to learn this type of coding on my own...

Comment: If you need to do this on a regular basis, it might be worthwhile to actually learn shell scripting. Stackoverflow is a good but not a totally reliable translator. :)

Comment: @Selase: just to clarify: Modern Windows (from Windows NT upwards) don't have any MS-DOS basis (or any DOS at all). They have a command line interpreter and a DOS-like text window. They are mostly compatible (with a compatibility layer), but it's **not** MS-DOS.

Comment: @ Joachim: Thanks for the clarification. but would a batch file such as the one with a .bat format run in the WinNT upwards environment?

Comment: Selase: Yes, the Windows command processor is mostly backwads compatible with command.com. In fact, most batch files in answers on this site will only run on Windows, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that formerly the script was required to be run with three arguments, like

```
rebuild_db.sh <db_name>  <user_name> <password>
```

Then later on some default values were added, and running without arguments (just `rebuild_db.sh`) is allowed. The default database name is `CARMPAS1`, but it will be read from the command line if there's at least one command-line argument.

Reading the first argument with a default value should work in a MS-DOS batch file like this:

```
set dbname=CARMPAS1
if not "%1"=="" set dbname=%1
```

Comment: I see...so how do i specify the argument in the Batch file format? specifically this part. ([ $# -gt 0 ] && DB=$1 || DB=CARMPAS1)

Comment: @Selase: I added that to the answer. Sorry about not reading the question fully in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The code is testing whether the number of arguments is greater than zero.
If it is, the environment variable DB is set to the value of the first argument, otherwise DB is set to the value "CARMPAS1".

Comment: how do i do that in Batch file format? testing the argument and setting the DB?